How to completely ignore test compilation in stage?
I'm running $ sbt 'allImages / Docker / stage' command on following configuration:
lazy val allImages =
  project
    .in(file("build/all-images"))
    .aggregate(p1, p2)
    .settings(
      Test / testOptions := Seq(Tests.Filter(_ => false)),
    )

How to completely ignore/skip test compilation ?
Test / testOptions := Seq(Tests.Filter(_ => false)) - just skip test running, not compiling.
ThisBuild / Test / compile / skip := true - ignore test compilation for all modules in project, but .settings(Test / compile / skip := true) has no effect
